Problem Running SeleniumBase Application over Docker Deployed on a Host
I have built a web app that scrapes some websites using SeleniumBase(https://github.com/seleniumbase). The program itself runs perfectly on localhost and also runs perfectly dockerized over my own machine when I run it. However, when I use a deployment site like "Railway" or "Render", it does deploy, build my docker publish it. But, when I run the program I am getting this error:
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 354, in execute

    self.error_handler.check_response(response)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response

    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:9222

from chrome not reachable

My Dockerfile looks like this:

# Use a smaller base image
FROM python:3.10-slim

# Set environment variables
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
ENV TZ=Europe/Istanbul
ENV LC_ALL=tr_TR.UTF-8
ENV LANG=tr_TR.UTF-8

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies and Chrome in one layer to keep image size smaller
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
     wget \
     gnupg \
     unzip \
     curl \
     ca-certificates \
     fonts-liberation \
     libappindicator3-1 \
     libasound2 \
     libatk-bridge2.0-0 \
     libatk1.0-0 \
     libcups2 \
     libdbus-1-3 \
     libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 \
     libnspr4 \
     libnss3 \
     libx11-xcb1 \
     libxcomposite1 \
     libxdamage1 \
     libxrandr2 \
     xdg-utils \
     locales \
     --no-install-recommends \
     && ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone \
     && wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb \
     && apt-get install ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb --yes \
     && apt-get clean \
     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Configure locale settings for Türkiye
RUN echo "LC_ALL=tr_TR.UTF-8" >> /etc/environment \
     && echo "LANG=tr_TR.UTF-8" >> /etc/environment \
     && locale-gen tr_TR.UTF-8

# Copy and install Python dependencies
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Copy the rest of the application
COPY . .

# Expose the ports for FastAPI and Streamlit
EXPOSE 8000 8501

# Command to run FastAPI and Streamlit
CMD ["sh", "-c", "uvicorn menu_crawler:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000 & streamlit run Hotel_Analyst.py"]

Maybe if I try to use the normal Selenium it could work but I want to use the SelenimBase for this specific program that I have.
Some part of my crawler.py looks like:

def g_crawler(url, is_area):
    menu_items = []
    if not is_area: 
        with SB(uc=True) as sb:
            sb_config.no_sandbox = True
            sb.driver.uc_open_with_reconnect(url, 10)
            try:
                sb.uc_gui_handle_cf()
                sb.sleep(3)

I tried to deploy my repo that has a Dockerfile that runs perfectly on local machine but raises errors on host machines like Railway or Render.
